# Creating separate DbContext for infrastructure modules such as handlers or filters

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, simple-injector

I'm registering my DbContext using Simple Injector on per web api request basis:

```
container.RegisterWebApiRequest<IModelContext, ModelContext>();
```

But also have a delegate filter created per web request as well:

```
container.RegisterAll<DelegatingHandler>(
    ...
    typeof(DelegatingHandlerProxy<TraceRequestHandler>)
    ...
);
```

which saves some info about a request in the db:

```
public class TraceRequestHandler(ITraceRequestRepository r) : DelegateHandler
public class EntityTraceRequestRepository(IModelContext c) : ITraceRequestRepository
```

what causes all kinds of EF multi-threading exceptions:

> The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
>
> A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
>
> The connection is not open.
>
> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

in a controller/repository such as:

```
public ProductController(IProductRepository r) : ApiController
public EntityProductRepository(IModelContext c) : IProductRepository
```

Once request tracing is removed, everything works fine.

How to register db context separately for 'general purpose' modules and for infrastructure modules?

Comment: This might be an indication that your `DbContext` is cached as singleton somewhere. Might it be that you don't show us some relevant parts of your configuration?

Comment: @Steven: I seems to be a race condition always won but the handler (create context, open connection, save data, dispose everything) and the controller (job is done at the moment of its instantiation so context is in an unusable state)

Comment: @Steven: I could register handler using a func factory and instantiate context manually `c.Register<DelegateHandler>(() => new TraceRequestHandler(new ModelContext()))` but I don't know how to register it and others then into `GlobalConfiguration.Handlers`.

Comment: @Steven: As a solution you could add `RegisterAll<TService>(params Func<TService>[])` but not sure how it correlates with the rest of the design.

Comment: Would you be able to build a minimal working solution the reproduces the problem, so I can run this, because I currently don't understand what is going on here, but I would like to help you out.

Comment: @Steven: Please take a look https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16224269/WebApiApplication1.zip

Comment: btw, I like how you use the imaginary C# 6 syntax to define your classes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in the code that you didn't show in your question, the `InfrastructureDelegatingHandler`:

```
internal sealed class InfrastructureDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler {
    private readonly IDbContext _dbContext;
    public InfrastructureDelegatingHandler(IDbContext dbContext) {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TraceRequest(request));
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    private void TraceRequest(HttpRequestMessage request) {
        DbRawSqlQuery<string> query = 
            ((EfDbContext)_dbContext).Database.SqlQuery<string>(
            "select name from sys.indexes");
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", query.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

The problem is in the following line:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TraceRequest(request));
```

In this line you start new task that calls TraceRequest. TraceRequest however uses the `_dbContext` and you never await for that created task, which means that it will run in the background. In other words, your `EfDbContext` is used from multiple thread simultaneously.

Your problem will disappear when you change the code to the following:

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TraceRequest(request));
    var message = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    return message;
}
```

Comment: Yay! Thank you. Was always wondering should I await Task.Factory.StartNew(). Did its behavior change since .NET 4.0? Because usually it isn't awaited, I mean from the tons of times I saw how it's used. It's hard to google (due ambiguous keywords) for this exact use case and results/opinions differ.

Comment: @abatishchev Whether or not you need to await depends on what you want to achieve. If you really want the operation to run in the background, you obviously don't want await. But in that case you should pull a new object graph from the container in the background thread, to prevent the issues you are getting. Read [this](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#work-with-dependency-injection-in-multi-threaded-applications) for more information.